# libspotify API: track index

Tags: spotify

Is there any way to get the track index in an album? or given a track URI, is it possible to know its index or offset in the album (assume the track belongs to an album) without walking through the whole album?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes he is referring to sp_track_index, wich is only accessible through a album browse.

[see libspotify documentation for sp_track_index here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/group__track.html#ga25c1df9d32fd58f243397740b29c3f61)

What you need to do is something along the lines of:

1. call sp_albumbrowse_create for the album of sp_track that you have
2. wait for the callback fired when created/loaded
3. get sp_track_index from that track. Preferably you put the specific track in userdata to be passed on to the callback to be used with comparison.

Note: getting sp_track_index outside of an browse, will always return 0.

[See Browse example here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/docs/12.1.45/browse_8c-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do an album browse for the target album. Once you've done that, you can get the track's index.

Comment: Do you refer to the API **sp_track_index**?